# Closed-Form solution for system of simple nonlinear equations

Tags: analysis, nonlinear-system

I am interested in analytical solutions for a system of nonlinear equations.

**Motivation**: The source of the question is a very convinient method to [create random matrices with special properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726844/matlab-fast-creation-of-random-symmetric-matrix-with-fixed-degree-sum-of-rows). Mathematica can give me solutions up to certain sizes of the linear system, but I would like to have it for arbitrary size N. I can also use numerical algorithms (which I am doing at the moment), but for N in the order of $N\approx10.000$, they are quite slow.

**System of nonlinear equations**:

$$
(w_i \cdot \sum_{j=1}^N w_j) - w_i^2 = d_i
$$
for $i=1...N$, and $w$ and $d$ are vectors with $N$ dimensions, and $w_i$ and $d_i$ is the $i$-th component of the vector. Both $d_i$ and $w_i \in \mathbb{R_+}$. I am providing the vector $d$ (i.e. N real non-negative numbers), and want to solve for $w_i$. Is there a way to solve this system analytically for arbitrary N?

---

**Edit**: For clarification, if N=3 we have the following system of equations:

$$
w_1 \cdot (w_2 + w_3) = d_1 \\
w_2 \cdot (w_1 + w_3) = d_2 \\
w_3 \cdot (w_1 + w_2) = d_3
$$

with $w_i, d_i \in \mathbb{R}$. For a given vector $d=(d_1,d_2,d_3)$, I want to get $w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$.

---

**Edit2:** I think I see a way how it could be solved, but I'm not certain:

Let's set $c=\sum_{j=1}^N w_j$, which is the sum of all weights. What we have now:

$$c \cdot w_i - w_i^2 = d_i \\
w_i^2 - c \cdot w_i + d_i = 0
$$
which has two solutions:

$$w_{i_{1,2}} = \frac{c}{2} \pm \sqrt{ \left(\frac{c}{2}\right)^2 - d_i}
$$
and the normalisation constant $c$ can be calculated by the sum of all weights:

$$\sum_{j=1}^N w_j = \sum_{j=1}^N \left(\frac{c}{2} \pm \sqrt{ \left(\frac{c}{2}\right)^2 - d_j} \right) = c
$$

Is this correct? Do you know an analytical solution for c?

Comment: Put $a_{ij}=w_iw_j$ then the $a_{ij}$ satisfy a set of linear equations which can be solved.

Comment: Thank you, that is correct. But how can one go from $a_{ij}$ to the actual $w_i$? Is it simpler than the original problem? I can not see how one could do it at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $a_{ii} = w_i^2$.

Comment: wow! i wonder how i missed that cute trick. that's a really great technique!

Comment: But actually, $a_{ii}$ is never mentioned in the equation system, so i only get values for $a_{i,j}$, right? It feels like i'm missing some simple final step.

Comment: For $w_iw_j = a_{ij}$ and assuming, as you say, the $w_{i}$ are positive then $ln(w_i)+ln(w_j) = ln(a_{ij})$. Since you have the $a_{ij}$, you now have a set of linear equations for the $ln(w_i)$.

Comment: Looking at it again, my first comment is a bit optimistic! The $a_{ij}$ create more variables than there are equations. There are N equations but $\frac{1}{2}(N-1)(N-2)$ of the $a_{ij}$ and the $a_{ij}$ are not independent of each other. Not sure the approach can be salvaged...

Comment: The solutions are the intersections of $N$ hyperquadrics and if I am right, there can be $2^N$ of them. This is bad news.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: For N=3, I only get 2 solutions, where only one fulfills $w_i > 0$ for $d_i >0$. Could you please explain more what you observed? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a research question?  Could it be suitable for MathOF?

Comment: @BrianTung i was thinking about it, but first wanted to see whether I miss something, by asking it at math.SE with a bounty. And I think my 2nd Edit shows some kind of solution. If the final equation for c can be solved, the equation is fully answered. But maybe I'm missing something, the multiple solutions for the weights are confusing me.

Comment: @nico: in your newest formula there are $N$ independent $\pm$ signs, hence $2^N$ possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n=3$ is rather easy: $w_i$ satisfies a quadratic polynomial.

For $n=4$, each $w_i$ satisfies a rather nasty polynomial of degree $8$
(but involving only even powers).  Thus there is a solution in terms of radicals, but it won't be pleasant.

For $n=5$, it seems each $w_i$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $22$.
A solution in radicals is not to be expected.  Thus with $d_1 = -7, d_2 = 3, d_3 = 9, d_4 = 7, d_5 = 8$, $w_5$ satisfies
$$ 81\,{w_{{5}}}^{22}+7074\,{w_{{5}}}^{20}+198792\,{w_{{5}}}^{18}+2887764
\,{w_{{5}}}^{16}+23487600\,{w_{{5}}}^{14}+99587008\,{w_{{5}}}^{12}+
69082752\,{w_{{5}}}^{10}-1402988992\,{w_{{5}}}^{8}-6995300352\,{w_{{5}
}}^{6}-14191984640\,{w_{{5}}}^{4}-13095665664\,{w_{{5}}}^{2}-
4492099584 = 0
$$

EDIT: This is an irreducible polynomial of degree $11$ in $x = w_5^2$.  Maple doesn't do Galois groups of polynomials of degree $11$, but GAP does, and confirms that its Galois group is $S_{11}$.  In particular, there is no
solution in radicals.

Comment: Thank you Robert, very interesting. Could you please mention how you get to the 8 and 22 degree polynomial equation for $w_i$, I can not see it unfortunatly. It seems my Edit2 already nearly has a solution within a quadratic polynomial equation - could you maybe point out why it is actually much more complicated? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used Maple to compute a Groebner basis.

Comment: Thank you! I'm surprised that this scales in such a bad way. 2, 8, 22 (https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C8%2C22). Do you think this is a no-go for an analytic solution, or could there be a different method to attack that problem?

Comment: It certainly puts constraints on the kinds of "analytic" solution you could have.

Comment: I find your answer wonderful (and the result unfortunate of course :) ). I wonder what how to interpret it? Does it mean that one can not find a solution using your approach, or does it say more such as "very likely there is no analytical solution with known methods, as it would solve high-order polynomials - which is known to be very difficult"? I'm asking as I want to know whether it would make sense to transfer the question to MO. I would be interested in your opinion, thank you!

Comment: I suspect this might not be well-received at MO.  
First of all, "analytical" or "analytic" is not the right word.  To a mathematician, "analytic" means "locally given by a convergent Taylor series".  What you mean is more like "closed form", but that's still ambiguous: exactly what kinds of special functions are you going to allow?  For example, some high-order polynomials can be solved by generalized hypergeometric functions, theta functions, etc.  Would you be happy with that?

Comment: Also, if you're really interested in $N \approx 10,000$, algebraic methods are likely to be essentially useless.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think your answer is the best I can hope for.

Answer (score 0):

For $$c^2\gt 4d_j$$

$$\sqrt{c^2-4d_j}=c\sqrt{1-\frac{4d_j}{c^2}}\approx c\left(1-\frac{2d_j}{c^2}\right)=c-\frac{2d_j}c,$$ with a relatively good approximation.

Summing,

$$\sum_{j=1}^N\left(c\pm\left(c-\frac{2d_j}c\right)\right)=2c.$$

With $M$ positive signs,

$$Mc-\frac{d}c=c,\\c=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{d}{M-1}},$$

where $d=\sum_{j=1}^N\pm d_j$.

This might give you reasonable approximations to start Newton's iterations or maybe just fixed-point.